# Electric breaker tripping without anything plugged in

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

My electric panel is outside and the door was open during a heavy rain. Not much rain got into the panel, but a small amount of water and condensation did.   One breaker would trip for a few hours, but is now working.  Another breaker continues to trip without anything plugged in.  Could there be some water damage to this panel that makes it trip?  Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Do any of these breakers have "TEST" buttons on them?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Yes, the breaker in question immediately trips when I hit the test button.  Thoughts?

Comment: I'm more concerned with the fact that the breaker has a TEST button.  That indicates that it has additional diagnostics designed to detect (among other things) water damage downline in the circuit.  So it could be from any part of the wiring getting wet.

Answer (score 1):

I would bet that the breaker is toast. GFCI receptacles for outdoor use are required to be WR or weather resistant rated. I have not seen this listing on the GFCI breakers I have installed. So if it got wet from the door being open and trips it sounds like time for a new one.

You could always swap a working one with the one that keeps tripping to see if it’s possibly a real circuit issue.
If that breaker continues to trip it’s time to replace it. Molded breakers when faulty are by code not repairable. Could it be dried out like a cell phone? Maybe I have never tried this.